# How to equate `var` variable to another query

Tags: c#, linq, casting, type-conversion

I have `var`variable called retVal which equals to some query. After some conditions I want to equate it to another query. But I get an error like `implicit cast of type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>" in "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#2>" is impossible`. You can ask me why I don't want to define another `var` variable. Because this one is used in `foreach` cycle. Let's have a look on the code:

```
var retVal = from groupItem in result.AsEnumerable()
                             where groupItem.Sms.First().amountOfParts == (
                               (from item in rawSmsList.AsEnumerable()
                                where item.referenceNumber == groupItem.Sms.First().referenceNumber
                                select item).Count()
                             )
                             select new
                             {
                                 Value = groupItem.Value,
                                 Sms = groupItem.Sms
                             };
                //CONDITION
                if (retVal.ToArray().Length==0)
                {
                    //HERE I NEED TO RETVAL EQUATE NEW QUERY
                    retVal = from groupItem in result.AsEnumerable()
                                 where groupItem.Sms.First().amountOfParts == (
                                   (from item in rawSmsList.AsEnumerable()
                                    where item.senderNumber == groupItem.Sms.First().senderNumber
                                    select item).Count()
                                 )
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Value = groupItem.Value,
                                     Sms = groupItem.Sms
                                 };                        
                }

                foreach (var item in retVal)//FOREACH EXPECTS THE SAME RETVAL!!!
```

So how to cast different queries to the same `var` variable? Or how to find type of `var` variable and then cast it to a new defined variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) means implicitly typed variable, that means its type will be determined at compile time, So on your first usage it will be assigned an anonymous type, in your second you are trying to assign it a different anonymous type, you can't do that.

You can modify your code to use a class instead of anonymous object and then project to that, then you will be to do what you are doing now. You can create the class like:

```
public class MyClass 
{
   public int Value {get;set;}
   public string Sms {get;set;}
}
```

and then project it by modifying your select statement as:

```
var retVal = ......
             select new MyClass
               {
                  Value = groupItem.Value,
                   Sms = groupItem.Sms
               };
```

Comment: Perhaps [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073.aspx) could be used here to compare the results of the two anonymous-typed results.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, I think by equate OP means to assign the result of the new query to existing `retVal`, its kind of confusing but from the code it seems so

Comment: There is no any way to cast one anonymous type to another?

Comment: @Habib Ah yes you're right. Ares, you are not equating (`==`), which means checking for equality. You are *assigning* (`=`) which means setting the value of.

Comment: @Ares, I am not sure if there is any way, but you can create your own class with `Value` and `SMS` as properties and then project to that. instead of using Anonymous type

Comment: @Ares Nope.  You should use an existing type, or define a new type (as Habib just suggested) to get the query's output type to be compatible.  Try `select new Tuple<int, string>(groupItem.Value, groupItem.SMS)` (assuming int and string).

Comment: @Ares, check the updated answer, which is using a class and project the result to that particular class.

Comment: Haha "check" the answer. Communication breakdown there, but it worked out well.

Answer (score 3):

The anonymous class you're using for your projections looks the same to us, but they're two separate classes as far as the compiler is concerned, which is why you'll see AnonymousType#1 and AnonymousType#2 in the error.

One solution is to simply select "groupItem" instead of projecting with an anonymous class since you're only using properties within the groupItem itself.  This would give you the same IQueryable type.

Side note: you should replace "retVal.ToArray().Length == 0" with "!retVal.Any()"

Answer (score 3):

To add to Habib's answer:

Just create an actual class instead of using the anonymous type (which is a different class every time you use it). I don't know the types from your example so you'll have to specify:

```
public class ValueSmsThing          // Give it a better name!
{
    public IDontKnow Value { get; private set; }    // specify the type!
    public SmsNumber Sms   { get; private set; }    // !!

    public ValueSmsThing( IDontKnow value, SmsNumber sms) {
        Value = value;
        Sms = sms;
    }
}
```

And then in your query, instead of using the anonymous type:

```
 select new
 {
     Value = groupItem.Value,
     Sms = groupItem.Sms
 };
```

Use the concrete class you created

```
select new ValueSmsThing( groupItem.Value, groupItem.Sms );
```

Then your `for` loop will know to iterate over `ValueSmsThing`s.